# How do I compute the inverse Fourier transform of a singular function?

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $x\ge 0 $ and $y \ge 0 $ and consider a following improper integral.

\begin{equation}
I(x,y) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}} \frac{(-1-\imath k y)}{k^2} e^{\imath k (x-y)} dk
\end{equation}

We calculate this integral in two different ways.

First way:

\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}} e^{\imath k x} \cdot \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}} z e^{-\imath k z} 1_{z \ge y} dz \cdot dk \\
&=&\int\limits_y^\infty z \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}}  e^{\imath k (x-z)} dk \cdot dz \\
&=& \int\limits_y^\infty z \delta(z-x) dz \\
&=& x \cdot 1_{x > y}
\end{eqnarray}

Second way: We split the integral in question into two parts.

\begin{eqnarray}
I_1 &=& \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}} \frac{e^{\imath k (x-y)}}{(\imath k)^2} = |x-y| \cdot \pi \\
I_2 &=& (-\imath y) \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}} \frac{1}{k} e^{\imath k (x-y)} dk = y sign(x-y) \cdot \pi \\
&&\Longrightarrow \\
I &=& I_1 + I_2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} x & if \quad  x>y \\ -x & if \quad x< y \end{array} \right. 
\end{eqnarray}

The results are different so there must be an error somewhere. Now, I know that the second way is correct because I tested it numerically using the following code:

```
M = 100; eps = 10^(-4); {x, y} = 
 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
NIntegrate[1/k^2 Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, -M, -eps}] + 
 NIntegrate[1/k^2 Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, eps, M}] - 
 2 Cos[eps (x - y)]/eps
-Abs[x - y] Pi

NIntegrate[ (-I y)/k Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, -M, -eps}] + 
 NIntegrate[ (-I y)/k Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, eps, M}]
 Pi Sign[x - y] y // N

NIntegrate[1/k^2 (-1 - I k y) Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, -M, -eps}] + 
 NIntegrate[1/k^2 (-1 - I k y) Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, eps, M}] + 
 2 Cos[eps (x - y)]/eps

Pi (Abs[x - y] + Sign[x - y] y)
```

[image]

This means that the first way is wrong. Indeed in the first way we expressed the result through a double integral and then swapped the order of integration. The assumptions of the  Fubini's theorem are not satisfied because the double integral from the modulus of the integrand does not exist.

Update: I have checked numerically that in the first approach the step from the definition to the first line, i.e. the expression as the double integral over $z$ and $k$, is wrong. Other steps seem to be right.

```
In[1222]:= M = 20; eps = 10^(-4); {x, y} = 
 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
If[x < y, tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp;];
(NIntegrate[1/k^2 (-1 - I k y) Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, -M, -eps}] + 
   NIntegrate[1/k^2 (-1 - I k y) Exp[I k (x - y)], {k, eps, M}] + 
   2 Cos[eps (x - y)]/eps)/(2 Pi)
NIntegrate[ Exp[I k x] z Exp[-I k z], {k, -M, M}, {z, y, M}]/(2 Pi)
NIntegrate[z Sin[M (x - z)]/(Pi (x - z)) , {z, y, M}]
x If[x > y, 1, 0]

Out[1224]= 0.255426 - 1.41358*10^-16 I

Out[1225]= 0.481756 - 4.85956*10^-15 I

Out[1226]= 0.481756

Out[1227]= 0.46787318300471700236343631477297526124617114997482
```

This is strange because that step follows very easily  from rotating the integration contour in the complex $z$-plane and from elementary integration.

---

Having said all that my question is how can we salvage the first approach in order to get the right result? The use of Dirac's delta function is very handy and this function is well established in mathematics for a long time. So again, is it possible to get the correct result using the first approach?

Comment: The first method assumes the only antiderivative of $\delta$ is the unit step function, but $\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sgn}$ also works - which is the antiderivative that aligns with answer two. Distributionally you would need to argue what the correct $+C$ would be, or even more easily show that the correct antiderivative needs to be an "odd" distribution i.e. its kernel must be all even test functions.

Comment: To explain where the antiderivative comes in method one, the sifting property of the delta is not the fundamental property in the theory of distributions, it is the "integration by parts" definition of the distributional derivative which applies to all distributions equally. Heuristically applying "integration by parts" to the integrand in method one gives the resolution from my first comment.

Comment: @Ninand Munshi: Alright, so the problem is not with the Fubini theorem. It is just that after the third line in the first block I need to write $I = \int\limits_y^\infty z (1_{z>x}-C)^{'} dz$ then integrate by parts and at the end choose the constant $C$ appropriately.

Comment: @NinadMunshi: I have done what you suggested, i.e. replaced the Heaviside function by one half sign function as the antiderivative of the Dirac delta but this leads to exactly the same result in approach one. I can send you my write up if you want.